# Fresón Candela "temprano"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿Qué significa "temprano" en "[Fresón Candela temprano ALCAMPO PRODUCCIÓN CONTROLADA 400 g](https://www.alcampo.es/compra-online/alcampo-produccion-controlada/de-la-huerta/frutas/alcampo-produccion-controlada-freson-candela-temprano-apc-400-g/p/470965) "? RAE define "temprano" como "sembrado o plantío de fruto temprano", ¿implicando que el fruto fue plantado o sembrado demasiado pronto? ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**Fresón Candela Temprano**" es una variedad de fresa o frutilla que se caracteriza por ser de alta calidad y madurar más temprano dentro de la temporada.

"**Fresón**" es el término utilizado en algunas regiones de España para referirse a las fresas o frutillas (*un tipo de fresa de tamaño mayor que la ordinaria*), mientras que "**Candela**" es el nombre de una nueva variedad de fresa onubense, más concretamente producida en la localidad de Lepe (Huelva), que se obtiene por métodos tradicionales y naturales de "*residuo cero*" (*un tipo de modalidad de cultivo*).

Al decir "**Temprano**", se refiere a que esta variedad de fresa madura antes que otras variedades, lo que puede ser una ventaja para los agricultores que desean adelantar la producción y para los consumidores que desean disfrutar de fresas frescas antes en la temporada.

En resumen, "**Fresón Candela Temprano**" es el nombre de una variedad de fresa de alta calidad que sigue métodos tradicionales y que madura temprano en la temporada.

**P.D.** El proveedor de "Alcampo" ha dedicado 10 hectáreas a este cultivo de fresas para comercializarlo exclusivamente con la firma "Alcampo", este proveedor prioriza la lucha de plagas mediante control biológico frente al uso de productos químicos (***Producción Controlada***).